# Basis for a subspace of matrix $2\times2 $with sum 0 entries.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

Consider the subspace of matrices of the form $\left(\begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$ I have to find a basis. I was thinking for example of letting $3$ variables free and then the fourth will be the negative linear combination.

$$\left\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & b\\ c & d \end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix} -b-c-d & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right):b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\rbrace $$
Is that enough? In addition for here the dimension is $2$ right?

I have another idea of putting
$$\left\lbrace\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & b\\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0\\ c & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & d \end{matrix}\right), \left(\begin{matrix} -b-c-d & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right):b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\rbrace $$ all of these matrices are linearly independent so the dimension is $4$? I have a confusion here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basis:$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.\tag1$$It is clear thet each of these matrices belong to your space and that they span the whole space: if $a+b+c+d=0$, then $d=-a-b-c$, and therefore\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&-a-b-c\end{bmatrix}\\&=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}Finally, the set $(1)$ is linearly independent. So, it's a basis. Since it has $3$ elements, your space is $3$-dimensional.